# what is the problem/what the problem is

Tags: word-order

> I want to find out what is the problem.
>
> I want to find out what the problem is.

Do you consider these sentences to have different meanings?

On the one hand, the mean the same, but on the other they might mean different things. To me:

1 I know that there is a problem, but I don't know what exactly it consists of or what it poses.

2 I know that there is a problem, but I want to find out what it means to others.

Maybe I am wrong. Tell me what you think.

Comment: I don't consider that they have different meanings. The second one is standard usage.

Comment: Asking "am I wrong" is basically the same as asking for something to be proof-read, which is off-topic here.

Comment: But for an expert who can explain the reason why the two mean the same is of no importance whether there is asking "am I wrong" or something else. The question is brilliant on its own and there is no use looking for a pretext to veer off it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there inversion in "I want to understand what is it that allows non-alcoholics to understand alkies."?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74730/why-is-there-inversion-in-i-want-to-understand-what-is-it-that-allows-non-alcoh)